# Variable unexpectedly changes value

Tags: c

I have a while loop in my program in which a particle keeps moving until it has visited a certain number of places (given by the integer `placesToVisit`).

```
int dimensionLength=2;
int placesToVisit=pow(dimensionLength, 3);
while (numPlacesVisited<placesToVisit) {

  // Code which makes no changes or references to placesToVisit
  // at all (except a few printf commands for debugging).

}
```

My issue is that after many iterations of this loop `placesToVisit` suddenly changes its value to 1 (and hence ending the loop prematurely). It should have a constant value of 8. This variable is only used in the conditional statement of the `while` loop, there are no pointers to it and no other references made to it other than a few `printf` commands I threw in for debugging. What could be causing `placesToVisit` to suddenly change it's value?

Comment: Look for pointer/array operations that are referring to things on the stack.  If one of those goes out of bounds, it could trash the variable.

Comment: You need to show all of your code in cases like this. You're probably overrunning a buffer or trashing something else on the stack.

Comment: Does your `dimensionLength` ever grow beyond 1290 (cubic root of 2147483647, which, I presume, is the value of your `INT_MAX`)?

Comment: are you changing the value of placestovisit inside your loop,if yes,then it might be the problem,moreover if placestovisit is a constant then define it as one const int

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One likely explanation is you are getting undefined behavior, because you are somehow corrupting your callstack by writing to an invalid memory location (most likely writing beyond the boundaries of an array on the stack).  The variable `placesToVisit` is likely a casualty of your smashed stack.

However, there's no way to be sure without seeing your code.  I suspect that the code which you haven't posted reveals a buffer overflow somewhere.

Comment: After a bit more in-depth debugging I am confident that this is correct. However I ended up just rewriting the code from scratch and everything worked fine. Not sure where the error crept in but hey ho, thanks for your help!